# Plotting a function of another function

Tags: plotting, functions

Edit:
So I have several functions which come from other functions. For example:

```
beta [alpha_, sd_, rf_] := (1/2) - (alpha/(sd^2)) + 
   Sqrt[(((alpha/(sd^2)) - (1/2))^2) + (2*rf/(sd^2))];

Yss[alpha_, sd_, rf_, iss_] := (1/2) - (alpha/(sd^2)) + 
   Sqrt[(((alpha/(sd^2)) - (1/2))^2) + (2*(rf + iss)/(sd^2))];

optVS [wa_, ea_, ewi_, kapa_, alpha_, sd_, iss_, 
       rf_] := ((beta[alpha, sd, rf]/(beta[alpha, sd, rf] - 1))*(ea - 
           wa))/((beta[alpha, sd, rf]/(beta[alpha, sd, rf] - 1))*(ea - 
            wa) + ((Yss[alpha, sd, rf, iss]/(
            Yss[alpha, sd, rf, iss] - 1))*(kapa + wa - ewi)))  ;

VS[wa_, ewi_, kapa_, alpha_, sd_, rf_, ea_, 
       iss_] := ((beta[alpha, sd, 
          rf]/(beta[alpha, sd, rf] - 
           1))*((wa - ewi + kapa)/(1 - 
            optVS [wa, ea, ewi, kapa, alpha, sd, iss, rf])));
```

You can see that optVS is part of VS. What I would like to do is plot VS in Y-Axis and optVS in X-Axis.
I know that plots usually use a function and then a range for a variable like:

```
Plot[VS[wa, ewi, kapa, alpha, sd, rf, ea, iss],{iss,0,1}]
```

However, what I want to do is to see the values of VS for the corresponding optVS. Can someone help me?

Comment: It is very difficult to figure out what you want. Can you please provide more details in your post? What kinds of functions are `x` and `y`. If you want to parametrically plot as a function of `x`, why is `x[a,b]` in the definition of `y` rather than just just `x`? What are `c` and `d`? Parameters? -- if so, please provide specific values for them. Variables? -- if so, then `ParametricPlot` is probably not what you want. Without more details, this is likely to be closed as "unclear what you are asking".

Comment: Sorry, I still haven't figured out how to ask questions properly.. I will edit!

Comment: Can someone just tell me if I'm not getting answers because:
1)Stupid question
2)Impossible to do
3)Can't understand question

Comment: 1) and 3). It's beyond my concentration level to even read through all your code. Check for the questions with several votes and see how they are constructed, that may help you on your next one.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the functions `beta` and `Yss` are the ones defined in your other question, that is,

```
beta[alpha_, sd_, rf_] := (1/2) - (alpha/(sd^2)) + 
   Sqrt[(((alpha/(sd^2)) - (1/2))^2) + (2*rf/(sd^2))];
Yss[alpha_, sd_, rf_, iss_] := (1/2) - (alpha/(sd^2)) + 
   Sqrt[(((alpha/(sd^2)) - (1/2))^2) + (2*(rf + iss)/(sd^2))];
optVS[wa_, ea_, ewi_, kapa_, alpha_, sd_, iss_, rf_] := 
   ((beta[alpha, sd, rf]/(beta[alpha, sd, rf] - 1))*(ea - wa))/
   ((beta[alpha, sd, rf]/(beta[alpha, sd, rf] - 1))*(ea - wa) + 
   ((Yss[alpha, sd, rf, iss]/(Yss[alpha, sd, rf, iss] - 1))*(kapa + wa - ewi)));
VS[wa_, ewi_, kapa_, alpha_, sd_, rf_, ea_, iss_] :=
    ((beta[alpha, sd, rf]/(beta[alpha, sd, rf] - 1))*((wa - ewi + kapa)/
    (1 - optVS[wa, ea, ewi, kapa, alpha, sd, iss, rf])));
```

you can use `ParametricPlot` by picking any one of the parameters to get a parametric curve for `{optVS, VS}` for fixed values of the other parameters. You can also pick a second parameter to get a family of curves. In the following, this is done by using the parameter `wa` to parametrize a curve, and `ea` to get a family of curves and fixing the rest of the parameters.

```
alpha = 0.02; ewi = 50; iem = 0.02; iss = 0.05; kapa = 900; rf = 0.05; sd = 0.5;
labels = ("ea = " <> ToString[#]) & /@ Range[0, 400, 50];

Legended[ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{optVS[wa, #, ewi, kapa, alpha, sd, iss, rf], 
  VS[wa, ewi, kapa, alpha, sd, rf, #, iss]} & /@ Range[0, 400, 50]], {wa, 0, 400}, 
  PlotLabel -> Style["wa ∈ (0,400)", 20], AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 16]& /@ {"optVS", "VS"}),
  Axes -> True, Frame -> False, AspectRatio -> 1], 
 LineLegend[ColorData[1] /@ #, labels[[#]]] &@Range[Length@labels]] /. Line -> Arrow
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can pick any two of your parameters to play the role of `wa` and `ea` in the example above.

You can vary the fixed parameters using `Manipulate` (again borrowing pieces from your other question):

```
Manipulate[ With[{labels = ("ea = " <> ToString[#]) & /@ Range[0, 400, 50]}, 
        With[{n = Length@labels},
   Legended[ ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{optVS[wa, #, ewi, kapa, alpha, sd, iss, rf], 
     VS[wa, ewi, kapa, alpha, sd, rf, #, iss]} & /@ Range[0, 400, 50]], 
    {wa, 0, 400}, AxesLabel -> {"optVS", "VS"}, Axes -> True, Frame -> False, 
    AspectRatio -> 1] /. Line -> Arrow, 
   LineLegend[ColorData[1] /@ #, labels[[#]]] &@Range@n]]], 
 {{rf, 0.05}, .03, .05, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{iss, 0.05}, 0, 0.10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 {{sd, 0.5}, 0.0001, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{kapa, 900}, 0, 2000, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 {{alpha, 0.02}, 0, 0.20, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 {{ewi, 50}, 0, 300, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or, you can add `ea` to the `Manipulate` variables:

```
Manipulate[ ParametricPlot[{optVS[wa, ea, ewi, kapa, alpha, sd, iss, rf], 
    VS[wa, ewi, kapa, alpha, sd, rf, ea, iss]}, {wa, 0, 400}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"optVS", "VS"}, Axes -> True, Frame -> False, 
   AspectRatio -> 1] /. Line -> Arrow, 
 {{rf, 0.05}, .03, .05,  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 {{iss, 0.05}, 0, 0.10,  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 {{sd, 0.5}, 0.0001, 1,  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 {{kapa, 900}, 0, 2000,  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 {{alpha, 0.02}, 0, 0.20, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 {{ewi, 50}, 0, 300, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{ea, 50}, 0, 400}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Finally, you can also use a two parameter version of `ParametricPlot` to get a parametric region:

```
Manipulate[ParametricPlot[{optVS[wa, ea, ewi, kapa, alpha, sd, iss, rf], 
   VS[wa, ewi, kapa, alpha, sd, rf, ea, iss]},
  {wa, 0, 400}, {ea, 0, 400}, AxesLabel -> {"optVS", "VS"}, 
  Axes -> True, Frame -> False, AspectRatio -> 1, BoundaryStyle -> None,
  MeshFunctions -> {#3 &, #4 &}, Mesh -> {5, 5},  MeshStyle -> {Red, Blue}],
 {{rf, 0.05}, .03, .05, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{iss, 0.05}, 0, 0.10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 {{sd, 0.5}, 0.0001, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 {{kapa, 900}, 0, 2000, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 {{alpha, 0.02}, 0, 0.20, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 {{ewi, 50}, 0, 300, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Wow that is amazing! I am still digesting it slowly but thank you very much for your answer :D